# why does it this c program give segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, string-literals

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *str="hello";
    str[0]='H';
    return 0;
}
```

If I use an array I can do use subscript to assign the first character. What's different about using a char pointer here that causes a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 3):

In this code snippet

```
char *str="hello";
str[0]='H';
```

you are trying to change a string literal pointed to by the pointer `str`. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

So though in C opposite to C++ string literals have types of non-constant arrays it is always better to declare pointers to string literals with the qualifier `const`.

```
const char *str="hello";
```

You could declare a character array initialized by the string literal and change the array itself like

```
char str[] ="hello";
str[0]='H';
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, I got the answer from this wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Writing_to_read-only_memory

The char pointer declared like that writes to a read-only segment of the process, editing that gives a segmentation fault (specifically  `SEGV_ACCERR`  which is defined as `invalid permissions for mapped object` (see [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.8/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h#L231))

An array on the other hand similarly allocated will be done so on the stack and so can be edited.

Comment: It is not necessary that an array will be created on the stack. It can for example have static storage duration.